# SQL: Validate a quantity given a comma delimited set of ranges

Tags: sql

I need to 'validate' a quantity. Given any number x, return true or false if the number is contained in a comma delimited set of ranges and numbers. Example: valid numbers "1,5-10,25-50,100,500", some valid numbers would be 1,5,6,7,8,9,10, but not 11,12,51, etc.

Comment: How are you storing / passing this `comma delimited set of ranges and numbers`?  Would it be possible to store it in a table instead *(One row per pair, each value from each pair in its own field)*?  In general trying to store multiple pieces of information in a comma delimited list is a significant SQL-Anti-Pattern.  If you can describe the whole use case in more detail we may be able to supply you with a better pattern to solve it.

Comment: I can take the values and put them into a temp table if needed. This method was put in place because we generally put a very small set of numbers in the field and did not want to use our more advanced "floor" and "Step" method of valid numbers (floor 100, step 50 would mean 100,150,200,250, etc are valid). If we go to a separate table to store the values, we will end up using the table structure that already exists. We might do that at some point, just was hoping for a patch. It would mean making database modifications instead of just a procedure change.

Comment: Which RDBMS?  Different dialects have different string manipulation functions.  But what it sounds like you need to do *(other than find a better design)* is to create a `split_list` function *(many on the web for many different SQL dialects)* to create a row per comma separated value, then use more string manipulation to make MIN/MAX pairs, then you can join on it.  *(But you'll get nobbled by badly formatted strings, out-of-range errors, slow performance, maintenance headaches, etc, etc)*

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions! Depending on what I find, I think we will end up doing the work to add the relationships to our existing tables or alter our design slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert the string into a temporary table of min and max values, you can easily select the valid values.

Example in T-SQL (MS SQL Server):

```
declare @valid varchar(50) = '1,5-10,25-50,100,500'

declare @i int, @range varchar(10)
declare @t table(min int, max int)

while len(@valid) > 0 begin
    set @i = charindex(',', @valid)
    if @i = 0 begin
        set @range = @valid
        set @valid = ''
    end else begin
        set @range = left(@valid, @i - 1)
        set @valid = right(@valid, len(@valid) - @i)
    end
    set @i = charindex('-', @range)
    if @i = 0 begin
        insert into @t (min, max) values (cast(@range as int), cast(@range as int))
    end else begin
        insert into @t (min, max) values (cast(left(@range, @i - 1) as int), cast(right(@range, len(@range) - @i) as int))
    end
end

select
    n
from
    (values(1),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(51)) as x (n)
    inner join @t on n between min and max
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this (SQL Server 2008)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RunningNumbers](@anzahl INT=1000000, @StartAt INT=0)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
    WITH E1(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)), --10 ^ 1
    E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
    E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
    E8(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E4 a CROSS JOIN E4 b), -- 10 ^ 8 = 10,000,000 rows
    CteTally AS
    (
        SELECT TOP(ISNULL(@anzahl,1000000)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) -1 + ISNULL(@StartAt,0) As Nmbr
        FROM E8
    )
    SELECT * FROM CteTally;

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckRange
(
     @ValidTarget INT
    ,@rangeList VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @rangeParts XML=CAST('<root><r>'+REPLACE(@rangeList,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML);

    DECLARE @Count INT;
    SELECT @Count= COUNT(*)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Valid.X
        FROM @rangeParts.nodes('/root/r') AS rp(p)
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',p.value('.','varchar(max)'))>0 
                        THEN CAST('<root><r>'+REPLACE(p.value('.','varchar(max)'),'-','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML)
                        ELSE '<root><r>' + p.value('.','varchar(max)') + '</r><r>' + p.value('.','varchar(max)') + '</r></root>' END AS pr
        ) AS partsResolved
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT CASE WHEN @ValidTarget BETWEEN partsResolved.pr.value('(/root/r)[1]','int') AND partsResolved.pr.value('(/root/r)[2]','int') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS X
        ) AS Valid
    ) AS tbl
    WHERE tbl.X=1

    RETURN @Count;
END
GO

SELECT Nmbr,dbo.CheckRange(Nmbr,'1,5-10,25-50,100,500')
FROM dbo.RunningNumbers(70,-3)


DROP FUNCTION dbo.RunningNumbers;
GO
DROP FUNCTION dbo.CheckRange;
```

Comment: @user2207612: It could speed up a lot, if you create the "partsResolved" part on its own and pass it in, rather then create it over and over again. Hope this helps...